# Switch bold font in Urxvt at runtime

Tags: fonts, urxvt, escape-sequences

As seen in the [man page](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/doc/rxvt.7.pod#Can_I_switch_the_fonts_at_runtime), one can switch the font in Urxvt using:

```
printf '\33]50;%s\007' "xft:Terminus:pixelsize=20"
```

However, having the following line in `~/.Xdefaults` will cause bold fonts to not change:

```
urxvt*boldFont: xft:terminus:pixelsize=13
```

[image: Weird font mix in Urxvt]

How to decode `\33]50;%s\007` and what code to use, so that bold fonts are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to use for changing bold fonts is:

```
printf '\33]711;%s\007' "xft:Terminus:pixelsize=20"
```

The `\33]50;%s\007` is close, but not the right place to look.  For whatever reason, the link you reference is pointing to an incomplete page.  This copy of [urxvt(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/urxvt.7.html) lists the code `711` which you would use to specify that the *bold* font should be changed, e.g., using

```
\033]711;%s\007
```

The manual page documents codes 50 and 711 respectively as

> *Ps* = `50`
>     Set fontset to *Pt*, with the following special values of *Pt* (rxvt) **`#+`*n*** change up *n* **`#-`*n*** change down *n* if *n* is missing of 0, a value of 1 is used empty change to font0 n change to font *n*

and

> *Ps* = `711`
>    Set bold fontset to *Pt*. Similar to *Ps* = `50` (Compile styles).

By the way, the given font specification

```
"xft:Terminus:pixelsize=20"
```

looks odd: one would expect something like this because you *are* asking for a bold font:

```
"xft:Terminus:pixelsize=20:style=bold"
```